# Civi 5.9 - DB Error: no such table / cannot disable logging

Tags: logging, drupal-6

Drupal 6 / Civi 5.9 / Aegir

I deleted my log_civicrm_... tables and now am getting a "DB Error: no such table" across a range of CiviCRM actions including adding contacts, running cron etc.

Logging is switched on and I cannot disable it via Administer > System Settings >Misc (...) > Logging).

Is there another way? Is there a table or a file I can edit  or a command I can run to to disable logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling the logging functionality using API Explorer. Navigate from the menu link - `Support -> Developer -> API Explorer`.

[image]

Or using Drush(if drupal) -

```
drush cvapi Setting.create logging=0
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jitendra. The API Explorer way worked. After disabling via API I enabled via the UI which recreated the log files and solved my problem.